# Microsoft Graph SDK not providing draft/send status of appointment/event in rich notification

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, microsoft-graph-sdks

When adding any data from outlook add-in in a new outlook event's `Extended properties`, outlook saves the event as a draft and also sends a create event notification to all its subscribers.
Here when I try to find the state of Event when fetching the information about the event, I do not find any details weather user actually click on Send button or it is just a draft event.

Get event information from graph SDK

```
     graphEvent = await graphServiceClient
                  .Users[eventData?.CalendarEmailId]
                  .Events[eventData?.Id]
                  .Request()                  
        .Expand($"SingleValueExtendedProperties({_extendedPropertyFilter})")
                  .GetAsync();
```

Note: Outlook only save as draft and send notifications in `The new Outlook` mode.

Is there any way to find out if the user actually saves the appointment yet or not?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use IsDraft property of the eventmessage to detect the event is still in Drafts folder? Expecting this property in the notification seems unreal, notification is a way to tell something has changed. You should go back to graph API and get details about a meeting item and use IsDraft property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/eventmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0